# SQL: Date difference between last non-equal event

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table of the form below that has: `user id`, `product` activated, `event` that occurs and `time` that corresponds to the event that occurs.

```
UID | |Product | Event | Time
A      C1         F      2017-06-23
A      C2         S      2017-06-21
A      C1         S      2017-06-19
A      C1         S      2017-06-17
B      C3         F      2017-06-12
B      C3         S      2017-06-12
C      C2         F      2017-06-02
C      C2         F      2017-06-01
```

I would like to find the time difference from the previous`S` event to `F` current event for each user and product.

```
UID | |Product | Event | Time        | Days_Diff
A      C1         F      2017-06-23    4
A      C2         S      2017-06-21    NULL
A      C1         S      2017-06-19    NULL
A      C1         S      2017-06-17    NULL
B      C3         F      2017-06-12    0
B      C3         S      2017-06-12    NULL
C      C2         F      2017-06-02    NULL
C      C2         F      2017-06-01    NULL
```

I tried something like the below but it doesn't help me keep track of the last product and event

```
SELECT UID, Product, Event, Time,
       CASE 
       -- product is equal to last product
       WHEN Product = LAG(Product, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY UID, Product ORDER BY Time) 
       -- current event = F and last event = S
       AND Event = 'F' AND LAG(Event, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY UID, Product ORDER BY Time) = 'S' 
       -- subtract current time by the last time this product was activated
       THEN DATEDIFF('DAY', MAX(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY UID, Product ORDER BY Time 
                                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), Time) 
       END AS days_diff
FROM table
```

However this doesn't help me compare cases where a user has activated a product and has an `S` event not directly followed by an `F` event. E.g. a case as below

```
UID | |Product | Event | Time        | Days_Diff
A      C1         F      2017-06-23    4
A      C2         S      2017-06-21    NULL
A      C1         S      2017-06-19    NULL
A      C1         S      2017-06-17    NULL
```

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Are you using Postgres or Redshift?

Comment: @GordonLinoff changed the tag to Redshift only and SQL.

Comment: What should be the days_diff for data as you mentioned in above scenario?

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni added the result for that case

Comment: can there be multiple `S` and `F` events for a product,user combination? if so, what should the result look like?

Comment: @vkp yes there can be. The problem is actually solved now. Please see GordonLinoff's solution below with my edit in the answer's comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want the time from the earliest "S" to "F".  If so:

```
SELECT UID, Product, Event, Time,
       (CASE WHEN Event = 'F'
             THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,
                           MIN(CASE WHEN Event = 'S' THEN Time END) 
                               OVER (PARTITION BY UID
                                     ORDER BY TIME
                                     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                                    ),
                           Time
                          )
        END) AS days_diff
FROM table;
```

Note:  This uses Redshift's `DATEDIFF()` function.  The first argument (as far as I know) is a datepart, not a string.

EDIT:

I see, you want the "S" on the same product.  That is just a little different:

```
SELECT UID, Product, Event, Time,
       (CASE WHEN Event = 'F'
             THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,
                           MAX(CASE WHEN Event = 'S' THEN Time END)                                    
                               OVER (PARTITION BY UID
                                     ORDER BY TIME
                                     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                                    ),
                           Time
                          )
        END) AS days_diff
FROM table;
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for the days since the last `S` for that user and product

Comment: @Black . . . That is not what your sample results shows.

Comment: I have made an edit by adding another row to user `A`. Does that help?

Comment: @Black . . . I see.  `product` is also important.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had to make a cahnge to your code `MAX(CASE WHEN Event = 'S' THEN Time END) OVER (PARTITION BY UID, PRODUCT ORDER BY Time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` so now seems to work.

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni yes there can be multiple S and F events. I think the `ORDER BY Time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` should fix this. Correct?

Comment: @Black . . . Yes.  I left that out because the sample data had only one "F".